# Trying to update an image source in an imagebutton with data binding using a command in the viewmodel - not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

Please forgive the newbie question but I am struggling to understand where I have gone wrong...

I am trying to change an imagebutton (in a grid) by binding the image source in xaml:

```
    <ImageButton x:Name="playButton"
            Source="{Binding PlayImage}"
            Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="0"
            BorderColor="#fafafa"
            BackgroundColor="#fafafa"
            />
```

The ImageButton loads up with the correct 'play.png' initially.
The Command 'PlayCommand' is working with the binding. This should change the value of the PlayImage to show the 'pause.png' image when the user clicks the imagebutton. Although the value of the PlayImage variable is changed, the image will not update. Please can someone tell me what I am missing? Here is my ViewModel:

```
    public class SermonDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Sermon Sermon { get; set; }
    public ICommand PlayCommand { private set; get; }

    private ImageSource _playImage;
    public ImageSource PlayImage
    {
        get { return _playImage; }
        set
        {
            _playImage = value;
            SetProperty(ref _playImage, value);
        }
    }


    public SermonDetailViewModel(Sermon sermon = null)
    {

        if (sermon != null)
        {
            Title = sermon.STitle;
            MP3Filepath = sermon.SLink;
            PlayCommand = new Command(async () => await StartPlayer());
            _playImage = "play.png";
        }
        Sermon = sermon;

    }

    async Task StartPlayer()
    { 

        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(MP3Filepath);

        _playImage = "pause.png";
        Console.WriteLine(_playImage);
        Console.WriteLine(PlayImage);

    }
```

and this is my baseViewModel code which uses the class INotifyPropertyChanged and sets up the setProperty method:

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IDataStore<Item> DataStore => DependencyService.Get<IDataStore<Item>>();


    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    string mp3filepath = string.Empty;
    public string MP3Filepath
    {
        get { return mp3filepath; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mp3filepath, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

I would really appreciate some help here.....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try your code and do one sample to test, and I agree with Jason's opinion, please try to set PlayImage value, don't set  _playImage, I find that although the value of PlayImage has been updated, it is not bound to ImageButton.

Please change the code like following code:

```
public SermonDetailViewModel(Sermon sermon = null)
{

    if (sermon != null)
    {
        Title = sermon.STitle;
        MP3Filepath = sermon.SLink;
        PlayCommand = new Command(async () => await StartPlayer());
        PlayImage= "play.png";
    }
    Sermon = sermon;

}

async Task StartPlayer()
{ 

    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(MP3Filepath);

    PlayImage= "pause.png";
    Console.WriteLine(_playImage);
    Console.WriteLine(PlayImage);

}
```

I also do one sample that you can take a look:

```
<ImageButton
            BackgroundColor="#fafafa"
            BorderColor="#fafafa"
            Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"
            HeightRequest="50"
            Source="{Binding PlayImage}"
            WidthRequest="50" />

 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new SermonDetailViewModel();
    }
}

public class SermonDetailViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand PlayCommand { private set; get; }

    private ImageSource _playImage;
    public ImageSource PlayImage
    {
        get { return _playImage; }
        set
        {
            _playImage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PlayImage");
        }
    }

    public SermonDetailViewModel()
    {
        PlayCommand = new Command(method1);
        _playImage = "check.png";
           
    }

    private void method1()
    {
       
        PlayImage = "plu3.png";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been struggling with this all week! It was the SetProperty method that wasn't working. I changed this to use a RaisePropertyChanged method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Source="{Binding PlayImage, Mode=TwoWay }"
```

This can also help you with binding
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the image is still not updating....

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the private backing field, not the public property.  This means that the `PropertyChanged` event will not be raised

```
async Task StartPlayer()
    { 

        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(MP3Filepath);

        // should be PlayImage = "pause.png";
        _playImage = "pause.png";
        Console.WriteLine(_playImage);
        Console.WriteLine(PlayImage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this change still didn't update the image. Am I missing a step or should this work?

Answer (score 0):

It works with the code:

```
    private ImageSource _playImage;
    public ImageSource PlayImage
    {
        get { return _playImage; }
        set
        {
            _playImage = value;
            Notify("PlayImage");
        }
    }

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
```